# Excel VBA all worksheets string manipulation

Tags: vba, excel

I have this existing code that works if i save it against a specific worksheet:

```
Sub Replacer()
  Dim N As Long, i As Long

  For h = 1 To 2
     If h = 1 Then
        sLetter = "A"
     Else
        sLetter = "B"
     End If

     N = Cells(Rows.Count, sLetter).End(xlUp).Row

     For i = 1 To N
        If Left(Cells(i, sLetter).Value, 1) = "T" Then
           sTmp = Right(Cells(i, sLetter).Value, Len(Cells(i, sLetter)) - 1)
           Cells(i, sLetter).Value = sTmp
        End If
     Next i
  Next h
End Sub
```

The first 2 columns may have, for example "T2" where players listed are tied second. Other rows will simply have the number. I need to strip out the "T" so that the cell is strictly a number. I have many worksheets that are in the same format, but with different tables.

However, I would like it to be able to loop through all available worksheets and doing the same thing. I have found the basic syntax of the worksheet loop, but then I cannot get the correct syntax for the original loop to work within / inside this outer loop. And I would then save this function under the "thisworkbook" VBA section instead and call from there.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      ?????
Next ws
```

Can someone assist please?

p.s. I'm sure someone will also have a more succinct way for the search to go through columns A and B than I am currently using too.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you put `Option explicit`on top of your module. Half of your variables seem undeclared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to strip the `T` as you said. So I will base my answer in that statement.
Below will remove any `T` found in columns A and B in all worksheet.

```
Sub RemoveT()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A:B").Replace "T", ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect L42 and the simplest code! I wasnt sure that this would empty the whole cell contents, hence why I was doing the whole string length, left & right functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate each worksheet and then run your code which is not the cleanest but a feasible solution.

```
Sub ReplacerAll()
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Call Replacer
    Next ws
End Sub
```